How to kill VS Code Server on kubernetes pod similar to `Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host...`
I am using Kubernetes + Remote Development to attach to a Kubernetes pod.
The VS Code remote server some times occupy a lot of memory and connecting multiple times to the same pod may cause some the server to still run remotely on the kubernetes pod.
How can I kill the server in a similar fashion as Remote-SSH?
